# Rails undefined local variable or method `first' for ActiveRecord::NullMutationTracker:Class on local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

We are getting this error on all local setups of our project(currently) when we call any method like:

```
belongs_to :abc
after_create :some_method

def some_method
  if self.abc.saved_change_to_parent_id?
  ...
  // or even self.abc.parent_id_before_last_save
end
```

It gives:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `first' for ActiveRecord::NullMutationTracker:Class):

app/models/model_name.rb:50:in `some_method'
```

*Yes, there is not a full trace with rails internal file paths etc, i only get my project files trace. Maybe its some logger config issue, any help to get full trace will also be appreciated.*

There are no such issues i could find on internet, thats why posting here.

PS: Not posted on rails issue tracker(github issues) because i don't have minimal reproduction.

#### Stack

ruby: 2.4.3
rails: 5.1.5 (also tried on 5.1.7)
OS: Ubuntu 20, also tried on macOS

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE1:** Using byebug, i got to this trace, where error is occuring:

```
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/acts_as_singleton-0.0.8/lib/acts_as_singleton.rb:43
```

which is [here](https://github.com/stephencelis/acts_as_singleton/blob/master/lib/acts_as_singleton.rb#L43), so it is not directly from rails, but a very outdated gem we have in our code for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i posted in the update, issue was not with rails or anything, i used byebug to track trace and it was something like:

```
activemodel-5.1.5/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:384
activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:146
activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:319
activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:315
acts_as_singleton-859f49112c03/lib/acts_as_singleton.rb:43
```

The last line, should not be there, as we are not using `acts_as_singleton` on any of the involved models.

So after some tracking, it turned out issue with the gem. I have created a fork and used that fork. Here is the fork: https://github.com/ziaulrehman40/acts_as_singleton (forked it from another fork, which seemingly had some other fixes as well). And you can see my changes [here](https://github.com/ziaulrehman40/acts_as_singleton/commit/fe55b83ec3c2efc516f62c50f3003c18315be64a).

### What was the issue?

This gem writes a module named `Singleton` within `ActiveRecord` module. Which seems ok, unless you realize that there is another module named Singleton already. Whihc is being included in:

```
gems/activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_mutation_tracker.rb:83

class NullMutationTracker # :nodoc:
    include Singleton
...
```

So as you can see, this Singleton module gets overriden(or expanded, not sure) un-intentionally by that outdated gem(`acts_as_singleton`).